# SharePoint 2010 - Page Viewer

Tags: sharepoint-2010, web-parts, html

I would like to use the Page Viewer web part to display an html page with some java script. That page is to be hosted as a stand-alone page within SharePoint (perhaps under Shared Documents folder).

The problem is this: when I point the Web Part to use the page, it prompts me to save the html file rather than displaying its content inside the web part.

I am following general rules to create the html file:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <head>
     <title>My Little SharePopint Page</title>
   </head>
   <body>
     <div id="PlayerName">
     </div>
     <div id="display">
     </div>
   </body>
 </html>
```

So I just need the page to be displayed inside the Page Viewer web part - and not to be prompted to save it as a file.

Answer (score 1):

You web application configuration is forcing your users to download the file, this is by design and by default, you can change it in "Web Application General Settings" in central administration.  look for "Browser File Handling" make sure its not strict. Check [technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262107.aspx)
page about this setting.

This can have security implications (Like loading PDF files inside the browser windows). There are other ways to accomplish this using js.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove everything north and south of the body tags first, they are already present through SharePoint. Then load the file (with just the div content) to your doc library and use the page viewer to point to that file.

I note that you are using PlayerName, impling that there is some type of flash/video player content to come later, depending on the object settings used that will also cause a "download" file display too.

Comment: No, it's still prompting me to download the file. I now only have the div tags.